# Mass saving xls as csv

Tags: vba, excel

here's the trick. gotta convert 'bout 300 files from xls to csv, wrote some simple macro to do it, here's the code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
wb.Activate

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\samplepath\CBM Cennik " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & " 2010-04-02.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Next wb
```

but it doesn't do exactly what i want - saves file **"example.xls"** as **"example.xls 2010-04-02.csv"**, what i need is **"example 2010-04-02.csv"**

need support guys ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to remove the extension in your filename.

Instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Name` use

```
Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
```

to remove everything after the last `.` in the filename (including the `.`).

Comment: BIG THANKS! :) you've saved the day.

Comment: one more problem - it separates columns with "," , but i need ";" as a column separator. any quick solution? i'd be gratefull.

Comment: You could try `local:=true` or `local:=false` as parameter to your call to `SaveAs`. If that does not help, please ask another question on StackOverflow - that's how it works. One question, one answer :) And you can/should accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: ok, it's my first question here, so thanks for your support ;)! answer marked as helpful.

Comment: Thanks, welcome to StackOverflow :) Did the `local` parameter help?

Comment: local:=True worked great! well, already love this place. one more time - thanks, man. now my work is done ;)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty method is to

```
Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

`local := true` - took the values from the Control Panel Regional settings and therefore got that variable as a delimiter instead of the "," (comma). Fantastic